# error on empty textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I want to search on grid view i use this code:

```
protected void search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string qu = "SELECT * FROM [USERS] WHERE (([kind] = @kind) or ([family] LIKE '%' + @family + '%') or ([name] LIKE '%' + @name + '%') or ([username] LIKE '%' + @username + '%') or ([tarikhozviyat] < @tarikhozviyat) or ([tarikhozviyat] > @tarikhozviyat2))";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qu, con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", nametxt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@family", familytxt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kind", kind.Text);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", usernametxt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tarikhozviyat", sdatetxt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tarikhozviyat2", edatetxt.Text);
    con.Open();

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    ShowData();
}
```

if i fill just several textboxes but not all of them it ask me to fill all to run search

Comment: So if i understand from your question you want add some code to ask to fill all ?

Comment: someone wants to search just on username, someone want search on name and family and... so they need to fill username textbox or name and family text boxes not all textboxes but it ask me to fill all and i do not want fill all

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line:

```
string qu = "SELECT * FROM [USERS] WHERE (([kind] = @kind) or ([family] LIKE '%' + @family + '%') or ([name] LIKE '%' + @name + '%') or ([username] LIKE '%' + @username + '%') or ([tarikhozviyat] < @tarikhozviyat) or ([tarikhozviyat] > @tarikhozviyat2))";
```

With

```
string qu = "SELECT * FROM [USERS] WHERE (@kind='' or [kind] = @kind) and (@family ='' or [family] LIKE '%' + @family + '%') and (@name = '' or [name] LIKE '%' + @name + '%') and (@username = '' or [username] LIKE '%' + @username + '%') and (@tarikhozviyat='' or [tarikhozviyat] < @tarikhozviyat) and (@tarikhozviyat2 = '' or [tarikhozviyat] > @tarikhozviyat2))";
```

It will search any combinations of parameters which some of them may be empty and the query will suppress them.

I hope to be helpful for you:)

Comment: when i fill usernametxt and click on search it pointed to nametxt and said please out fiil out this field.

Comment: Do the textboxes have `RequiredFieldValidator`(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78xxk8k.aspx) ?

Comment: No. let me know what happens when click on search and what you means "it pointed to `nametxt` and said please out fiil out this field."?

Answer (score 0):

You appear mostly ok on the query and parameters... You could do it one of multiple ways... I would suggest only add where clause and parameter IF it exists.

```
string qu = "SELECT * FROM [USERS] WHERE ";
string orClause = "";

if( !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( nametxt.Text ))
{
    qu += orClause + "[name] LIKE @parmName ";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("parmName", "%" + nametxt.Text.Trim() + "%");
    orClause = " or ";
}

if( !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( kind.Text ))
{
    qu += orClause + "[kind] = @parmKind ";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("parmKind", kind.Text.Trim());
    orClause = " or ";
}

etc... with rest of your criteria.


If no criteria, you can just add where 1=1...
if( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( orClause ))
    qu += " 1=1 ";
```

FEEDBACK...

You state it does not work... what part does not... the logic is accurate as all of your original query post was "OR" together.  If a user does not fill in a particular value for a field, you would just exclude that criteria anyhow.  If you meant to "AND" the criteria, just change or to and.  Example...

if you wanted a "KIND" AND the NAME was "whatever" AND ...

It should work as I do this regularly in some of my queries where not all criteria are required.

Not sure what you mean about the fill Nametxt, etc, but it MIGHT be a confusion about MySQL using "@" as variables and you have the same "name" as the "@name" for example.  What I have typically done to prevent such confusion is add a prefix to the expected parameter such as "parmName", "parmKind", "parm..."  Also, when defining the parameters, DO NOT use the "@" as the string.  See my revision above.

Comment: i done what you said but when i clicked on search it said fill nametxt,familytxt and etc.

Comment: @mrym, see revision, parameter naming and stripping "@" from the adding parameter...